# Filter subdocument in query result in App Sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have two types that are connected

```
type Auction @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  startingDate: AWSDateTime!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
  products: [Product] @connection(name: "AuctionProducts")
}

type Product @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  price: Int!
  ownerId: String!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
  auction: Auction @connection(name: "AuctionProducts")
}
```

I would like to query an auction and the products related to it BUT filtered by ownerId
The idea is that a user could not see the products in an auction that doesn't belong to him.

I would like to do it server side for security issue. I lost myself in filtering the products as if they were in the auction dynamoDB document but they are not.

I have no idea anymore… Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably figured it out by now, but you'll need to have an Auth service [configured](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react), Cognito being the easiest to work with. Then use the `@auth` directive on all of your schema types you'd like to be protected and visible only to owner:

```js
type Product @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner, ownerField: "ownerId"}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  price: Int!
  ownerId: String!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
  auction: Auction @connection(name: "AuctionProducts")
}
```